# prove of strict monotonicity when $f'(x)\neq0$

Tags: derivatives, monotone-functions

If $f(x)$ is differentiable on the interval I, and $f'(x)\neq0$ for all $x\in I$, prove that $f(x)$  is strictly monotonic on I.

My solution was to say that if $f'(x)\neq0$, then $f'(x)>0$ or $f'(x)<0$ , then $f(x)$ is either strictly monotonic decreasing or increasing, but I think my logic is flawed-- can anyone provide a correct solution? Or if the statement is wrong, providing a counterexample would be nice! Thanks!

Comment: Your reasoning is correct.

Comment: But f′(x)≠0 might imply that f is increasing in some places but decreasing in some other places-- that would not imply monotonicity on the whole function, would it?

Comment: doesn't that require f'(x) to be continuous?  differentiability of f doesn't necessarily mean continuity of f' , or does it?

Comment: I just noticed that. I deleted my comment.––Thanks for pointing out that mistake!

Comment: The result I should have used is Darboux's theorem: any function that results from the differentiation of another function has the intermediate value property. For more information, see this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux's_theorem_(analysis)

Comment: Thanks! But how does darboux's theorem help on this case?

Comment: Oh I think I get it-- suppose f'(a)>0 and f'(b)<0 for some a<b (the situation is same for a>b )  then by darboux's theorem there must exist a c in (a,b) such that f'(c)=0 which contradicts my first comment.

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

HINT.-Let $I=[a,b]$ and assume lenght of $I$ is finite. Take $a\lt x_1\lt x_2\lt b$. Over the compact $[x_1,x_2]$ the function $f$ take its maximun and minimun (global). Since $f'(x)\ne0$ these extremes should be taken in $x_1$ and $x_2$ then the function $f$ is strictly monotonic on $[x_1,x_2]$

You can end by letting $x_1$ and $x_2$ tend to $a$ and $b$ respectively.

Similarly you can do when the lenght of $I$ is infinite.